# Difficulty with caesar cipher

Tags: c++, encryption, char, caesar-cipher

I created a program which takes a 'word' and a num parameter as the shifting number. Example if the string is `Caesar Cipher` and num is 2 the output should be `Ecguct Ekrjgt`. But I want the punctuation, spaces, and capitalization to remain intact. Also I can't add a sentence. Just a word. I am not allowed to use strings.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  char name[50] = { '\0' };
  int cipherKey, len;

  cout << "Enter cipher key: ";
  cin >> cipherKey;

  cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
  cin >> name;

  len = strlen(name); // this code just inputs the length of a word. after spaces it won't calculate.

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    char temp = name[i] + cipherKey;
    cout << temp;
  }
  cout << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: char array don't add spaces.

Comment: `char`s are somewhat also numerical values (`'x'==120` for example). Use that as a hint and try to remember what if/ else is doing. Second hint: `'a'!='A'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To ignore punctuation**, I would suggest that inside your `for loop` you should put an `if` to select the punctuation that you want to leave unchanged. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if( name[i]==' ' || name[i]==',' || name[i]=='.' /*...etc...*/ )
        cout << name[i];
    else {
        char temp = name[i] + cipherKey;
        cout << temp;
    }
}
```

It's a tedious to type it out for each special puctuation character, but c++ is kinda like that :P

**To get the cipher working**: as mentioned in comments, the line

```
char temp = name[i] + cipherKey;
```

will not always do what you expect. Specifically you will want to wrap around if `name[i]+cipherkey` is off the end of the alphabet. I'll leave that for you to figure out. (hint: google 'ASCII values' to see how a `char` is represented in number form)

Comment: But what if the person enter 'z'? I want to move it back to 'a'.

Comment: Correct, hence why I said `Specifically you will want to wrap around if name[i]+cipherkey is off the end of the alphabet. I'll leave that for you to figure out.`